# Problems when importing a CSV file and persisting information in a database using Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, backend, jhipster, import-csv

I'm having a problem with a CSV data import code into the database. I'm using Java 11 with SpringBoot 2.7.3 REST API

I have a Report class that has a Many-To-Many one-way relationship with the SensorError class, where only Report knows about SensorError and not the other way around:

`@ManyToMany @JoinTable( name = "rel_report__sensor_error", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "report_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "sensor_error_id") ) private Set<SensorError> sensorErrors = new HashSet<>();`

I created a code to import CSV data:

```
public static List<Report> csvToReports(InputStream is, ReportRepository reportRepository,
        SensorErrorRepository sensorErrorRepository) {
    try (BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.defaultCharset()));
            CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(fileReader,
                    CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader().withIgnoreHeaderCase().withTrim());) {
        // Create an empty list to hold the SiraReports that will be parsed from the CSV
        // file
        List<Report> reports = new ArrayList<Report>();

        // Parse the SensorError objects from the CSVRecord
        Set<SensorError> sensorErrors = new HashSet<>();

        // Get an Iterable of CSVRecords from the CSVParser
        Iterable<CSVRecord> csvRecords = csvParser.getRecords();

        for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvRecords) {

            Report report = new Report(csvRecord.get("final_state"), Instant.parse(csvRecord.get("datetime_begin")),
                    Instant.parse(csvRecord.get("datetime_end")), csvRecord.get("cutting_time"),
                    csvRecord.get("total_time"));

            // Check if sensor_name, error_code and error_detail fields have values
            if (!csvRecord.get("sensor_name").isEmpty() || !csvRecord.get("error_code").isEmpty()
                    || !csvRecord.get("error_detail").isEmpty()) {
                // Create a new SensorError object using the data from the CSVRecord
                SensorError sensorError = new SensorError(csvRecord.get("sensor_name"), csvRecord.get("error_code"),
                        csvRecord.get("error_detail"));

                // Add the SensorError object to the Set
                sensorErrors.add(sensorError);
            }

            // Set the SensorError objects for the SiraReport object
            report.setSensorErrors(sensorErrors);

            // Save the SensorError objects to the database using the SensorErrorRepository
            sensorErrorRepository.saveAll(sensorErrors);

            // Add the Report object to the List
            reports.add(report);
        }

        // Return the List of Reports
        return reports;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to parse CSV file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This code works partially for my interest, in my CSV file:

```
final_state,datetime_begin,datetime_end,cutting_time,total_time,sensor_name,error_code,error_detail
TESTESENSOR,2022-09-30T18:15:00Z,2022-09-30T18:35:00Z,30min,40min, "sensor operador","operando","falha parcial","sensor navalha","erro mundial","falha total"
```

The code saves only the first SensorError Information inside a Report: ""sensor operador","operando","falha parcial"", but not the second information: ""sensor navalha","erro mundial","falha total"".

I already tried some things, like adding: Set sensorErrors = new HashSet<>();, inside the Loop, but then it saves the second SensorError Information and not the first one anymore. I also tried changing it to a List instead of Set, but it didn't solve the problem.

How to make it import more than one existing SensorError information in the CSV file to a single SiraReport?

Comment: what is "siraReport"? please provide the complete code, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: I apologize, it's a report and not siraReport. I fixed the code now.

Comment: It looks to me like you have 8 header columns, yet 11 columns of data... A formatting error won't explain it, as the total fields amount to an odd number

Comment: try running in debug mode: what is the length of "csvRecords"? what is the value of "csvRecord.get("sensor_name")" ? sensorErrors can only have one element, what is its contents? there is nothing "wrong" with your code, just debug it line by line and make sure everything goes to its right place.

Comment: @g00se , yes, this is what it has, however it has also tried to add corresponding header columns, however the result is that it will add the second SensorError information and not the first one anymore. when I create a JSON to save the Report with SensorError data it is created like this: ""sensorErrors": [{
            "sensorName":"sensor1",
            "errorCode":"404",
            "errorDetail":"complete failure"
            },
            {
            "sensorName":"sensor2",
            "errorCode":"400",
            "errorDetail":"partial failure"
            }
            ]"

Comment: *however it has also tried to add corresponding header columns* "it"? I don't really understand all that. Surely if the column headers do not correspond with the data, you are beginning with a corrupt csv file?

Comment: @TomElias In debug mode csvRecords has size=1. After he adds the Report data to the line, he enters the if for verification of the SensorError object and does the csvRecord.get for each one and at the end sensorErrors.add(sensorError), the following information appears in the debug record: "sensorError= "SensorError{sensorName='sensor operator', errorCode='operand', errorDetail='partial failure'}" sensorErrors will have size=1 at the end of the debug, but only with the first line of SensorError information

Comment: @g00se Sorry for my inconclusive answer, I added the headers to have 11 too, like this: "final_state,datetime_begin,datetime_end,cutting_time,total_time,sensor_name,error_code,error_detail, sensor_name, error_code, error_detail", this way would match with 11 columns of data, however the code will save the second SensorError information from the CSV file: ""sensor navalha","erro mundial","falha total"" and no longer the first info: ""sensor operador","operando","falha parcial"" when there were only 8 headers.

Comment: @g00se I think it's the way I'm sending the data in the CSV that's weird. As for a single Report I can have several SensorError information, I believe that the CSV should have something similar to this format: "final_state,datetime_begin,datetime_end,cutting_time,total_time,sensor_name,error_code,error_detail
TESTESENSOR, 2022-09-30T18:15:00Z,2022-09-30T18:35:00Z,30min,40min,"sensor operator","operating","partial failure"
TESTESENSOR, 2022-09-30T18:15:00Z,2022-09-30T18:35:00Z,30min,40min,"sensor navalha","erro mundial","falha total"

Comment: *As for a single Report I can have several SensorError information* But you're reading one csv record per Report. If you haven't even modeled your data correctly yet, it seems that the rest of the code, and this question, are premature

Comment: @g00se Indeed, you are correct. I could even in my question made prematurely, based on your answer, arrive at a possible solution. I will post it, because the way I was sending the CSV data and how the code was modeling it, it was doing the wrong thing for my purpose, as you correctly commented. Sometimes we need to be asked to be able to think better, something that happened thanks to your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, due to the questions made here in this topic, I could observe that my error was initially, in how the data were being sent, because if for 1 Report I have several SensorError information, then I would have to duplicate the data lines of the Report and include information other than SensorError to look like this:

> final_state,datetime_begin,datetime_end,cutting_time,total_time,sensor_name,error_code,error_detail
> TESTESENSOR,2022-09-30T18:15:00Z,2022-09-30T18:35:00Z,30min,40min, "sensor operador","operando","falha parcial"
> TESTESENSOR,2022-09-30T18:15:00Z,2022-09-30T18:35:00Z,30min,40min, "sensor navalha","erro mundial","falha total"

From there, I had to review my code due to questions from @g00se and @Tom Elias, arriving at this code that works:

```
public static List<Report> csvToReports(InputStream is, ReportRepository reportRepository, SensorErrorRepository sensorErrorRepository) {
    try (
        BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.defaultCharset()));
        CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(fileReader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader().withIgnoreHeaderCase().withTrim());
    ) {
        Map<String, Report> reportMap = new HashMap<>();
        List<Report> reports = new ArrayList<>();

        Iterable<CSVRecord> csvRecords = csvParser.getRecords();

        for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvRecords) {
            String datetimeBegin = csvRecord.get("datetime_begin");
            String datetimeEnd = csvRecord.get("datetime_end");
            String reportKey = datetimeBegin + datetimeEnd; // Create a new key using final_state and datetime_begin

            Report report = reportMap.get(reportKey);

            if (report == null) {
                report = new Report(
                    csvRecord.get("final_state"),
                    Instant.parse(datetimeBegin),
                    Instant.parse(datetimeEnd),
                    csvRecord.get("cutting_time"),
                    csvRecord.get("total_time"),
                );
            }

            // Check if sensor_name, error_code and error_detail fields have values
            if (!csvRecord.get("sensor_name").isEmpty() || !csvRecord.get("error_code").isEmpty() || !csvRecord.get("error_detail").isEmpty()) {
                // Create a new SensorError object using the data from the CSVRecord
                SensorError sensorError = new SensorError(
                    csvRecord.get("sensor_name"),
                    csvRecord.get("error_code"),
                    csvRecord.get("error_detail")
                );

                // Add the SensorError object to the Report
                report.addSensorError(sensorError);

                // Save the SensorError object to the database using the SensorErrorRepository
                sensorErrorRepository.save(sensorError);
            }

            // Save the Report object to the database using the ReportRepository
            reportRepository.save(report);

            // Add the Report object to the Map and List
            reportMap.put(reportKey, report);
            reports.add(report);
        }

        // Return the List of Reports
        return reports;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to parse CSV file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I had to create a method that performs an identification if the lines sent in the CSV refer to the same Report and add the SensorError information to the same Report object.

So now the code creates a new identifier using the datetime_begin and datetime_end field combination to check if there is an existing Report with the datetime_begin and datetime_end field combination. If there is no existing Report, it creates a new Report.

In summary, it will check the duplicated lines with Report information, if it is the same Report object and then it will register the different SensorError information for that Report object.

I am aware that a better check would be by ID, but this is generated sequentially by the application.